# Setup access permission to nexus

Tags: nexus

We have given anonymous user to upload files to nexus repository manager.But it was not a good practice.We need to limit access to each project.Only relevant users should have read access.How can i fulfill this requirement.

Currently we have created two repos lib-release-local and lib-snapshot-local and inside those repos we are managing our projects.In this design how we can implement permission schema.

Comment: What version of NXRM is this for?

Comment: @joedragons we are using 3.14.0.04 verison

Answer (score 0):

NXRM3 has a piece called content selectors, which are pretty much designed for what you're describing.  Using a query language you can create a privilege which limits what folks can see or do in a certain repository (or format).  Then you can assign that privilege to a role and that role a set of users (also removing the ability for them to view *).

See [documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-ContentSelectors) for more.  I also advice if you have questions about content selectors and their implementation asking on community.sonatype.com forums where the development team as well as support monitor.